# How to remove specific fields from environment table in the pytest-html report like Packages, Platform, Plugins

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I know how to remove the entire "Environment table" in the pytest-html report using (config._metadata = None)  but is there a way to remove certain fields from that table? I can also update the certain fields value using (config._metadata['Python'] = '3+') but could not find a way to remove the field from html report.

Comment: `del config._metadata[fieldname]` or `config._metadata.pop(fieldname)`?

Comment: @hoefling : tried with del and pop - did not work, was it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the fields in the beginning then use this hook in **conftest.py**

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata.pop("Platform")
    config._metadata.pop("Plugins")
```

Otherwise, if in the end of the test session you want to remove then

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    session.config._metadata.pop("JAVA_HOME")
```